# Handling multiple keys inside a switch block

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a Windows Forms Application where I am trying to Hide a panel on whenever a user presses the combination of F12 and ctrl key but I am getting the error     Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Keys' and 'Keys' . Thanks for your time.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //method to assign keys
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Down:                   
                SendKeys.Send("{Tab}");
                e.Handled = true;
                break;

            case (Keys.Control && Keys.F12): **// error here** 
                 this.panel3.Hide();
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2019

Comment: what version of c# - you can use pattern matching here

Comment: There's an easy way to accomplish this. If you don't already have a `MenuStrip` on your form, add one. Add an item to the MenuStrip (name: CtrlF12Combo). In the MenuStrip, click on your menu item. In the Properties Window, set `ShortcutKeys` property to `Ctrl+F12`.  Set `Visible` property to `False`.

Comment: You can also override `ProcessCmdKey` and just check `if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F12))` -- In this case, it's simpler to store and reuse different combinations of keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to `Hide()` on `Ctrl + F12` combination, you should check `e.Modifiers`:

```
...

case (Keys.F12): // On F12
  if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) { // On Ctrl + F12
    this.panel3.Hide();
  } 

...
```